# $f$ integrable, if either $A_n \uparrow A$ or $A_n \downarrow A$, then does it follow that $\int_{A_n} f \to \int_A f$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is integrable. If either $A_n \uparrow A$ or $A_n \downarrow A$, then does it follow that $\int_{A_n} f \to \int_A f$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: it is a consequence of a (more) general result that states the following.

**Theorem.** (Rudin, Real and complex analysis, Theorem 1.29) Suppose that $f \colon X \to [0,+\infty]$ is a measurable function. Then $$\varphi \colon E \mapsto \int_E f \, d\mu $$ is a measure.

In your case, the measure $\varphi$ is *finite*, since $f$ is integrable and not only measurable. The proof is based on the monotone convergence theorem.